# Setup keyboard and touchpad to a X230 Thinkpad on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, thinkpad

I started today to use Fedora 23, before I used Ubuntu and configured my keyboard and touchpad easily, but now it´s hard.

My keyboard layout is brazilian.

Thanks.

Comment: @Jakuje I tryed this command but didn´t worked when I restart the system. `setxkbmap -model thinkpad60 -layout br`

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > keyboard > Input Sources, and add a new input source that will be the keyboard layout you want to use

Comment: I didn´t found thinkpad keyboard layout

Comment: It's not about thinkpad keyboard. All keyboards follow a specific language it's a matter of knowing what language you use and setting it to that language. I use a thinkpad t430 and the keyboard is set for us English

Comment: If you look at Google, you will understand, the keys position are different